# Call log detect changing

Tags: android, logging, service, call

i have a question.
I read a lot of tutorial that explain how to read call.log but my problem is how can i put call log reader into a service to detecting change?
My application had to do some action when into call log there is a new outgoing call. Can someone help me?
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to detect incoming call, you have to broadcast the action : **ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED**

*If you want to launch the broadcast in a service :*

```
public class ServDelLog extends Service {
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("SERVICE", "STARTED");
        //-- Here is the filter 
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);
        filter.setPriority(-1);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        //-- Inser your Code here ----
        ScanCallLog(this); //-- For exapmle a function for scaning the log
        //
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    Log.d("SERVICE", "STOPPED");
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
    }
    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(action.equals(android.telephony.TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED)){
            //-- Because you've got to wait before the phone write into the call log
                new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) { 
                    public void onFinish() {
                        ScanCallLog(context);
                    }
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        // millisUntilFinished    The amount of time until finished.
                    }
                }.start();

            }
        }
    };
}
```

*The service can be set in your activity by calling :*

```
startService(new Intent(this, ServDelLog.class));
```

*And don't forget to add in your manifest :*

```
<service android:name=".ServDelLog" />
```